# Deserializing Issue in Azure Cognitive Services Form Recognizer client library for .NET - Version 3.1.0-beta.4

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I have a labeled model with a "label table". This model works well with the latest REST API, but not with the .NET Client Library 3.1.0-beta.4.
In cases where the model predicts an empty cell in the "label table", an InvalidOperationException occurs when the library deserializes the result.

[Exception Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDdVQ.png)

System.InvalidOperationException: The requested operation requires an element of type 'Object', but the target element has type 'Null'.    at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.EnumerateObject()    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.FieldValue_internal.DeserializeFieldValue_internal(JsonElement element)    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.FieldValue_internal.DeserializeFieldValue_internal(JsonElement element)    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.FieldValue_internal.DeserializeFieldValue_internal(JsonElement element)    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.DocumentResult.DeserializeDocumentResult(JsonElement element)    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.AnalyzeResult.DeserializeAnalyzeResult(JsonElement element)    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.AnalyzeOperationResult.DeserializeAnalyzeOperationResult(JsonElement element)    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.FormRecognizerRestClient.GetAnalyzeFormResultAsync(Guid modelId, Guid resultId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.RecognizeCustomFormsOperation.UpdateStatusAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models.RecognizeCustomFormsOperation.UpdateStatusAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Azure.Core.OperationHelpers.DefaultWaitForCompletionAsync[TResult](Operation`1 operation, TimeSpan pollingInterval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at KKELBelegAnalyzer.BelegAnalyzer.AnalyzeBeleg(Stream streamInput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with the same problem, this will be fixed on the next beta release in May.
See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/20495) OP submitted for more details.